# Format the results of a SQL case?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to format the results of a SQL case I have, but I have no idea how to do it.

```
SELECT ProductID, ProductName, WholesalePrice, UnitPrice as 'Current Price',
CASE
    WHEN CategoryID = 1 or CategoryID = 4 THEN UnitPrice * 1.2
    WHEN CategoryID = 6 or CategoryID = 8 THEN UnitPrice * 1.15
    WHEN SupplierID = 2 THEN UnitPrice * 1.08
    ELSE UnitPrice
    END AS 'New Price'
```

And the results I get are

```
Product ID | ProductName | WholesalePrice | Current Price | New Price
     4          Thing           19.11           22.00       23.7600000
```

I am trying to just have it formated fro Currency, but I am unsure. I am hoping to get it to look like this

```
Product ID | ProductName | WholesalePrice | Current Price | New Price
     4          Thing           19.11           22.00         23.76
```

I am working with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio on this in case that matters.

Comment: please tag with appropriate database platform.  all db platforms have some sort of ROUND function for this

Comment: SELECT ProductID, ProductName, WholesalePrice, UnitPrice as 'Current Price',
    CAST(CASE
    WHEN CategoryID = 1 or CategoryID = 4 THEN UnitPrice * 1.2
    WHEN CategoryID = 6 or CategoryID = 8 THEN UnitPrice * 1.15
    WHEN SupplierID = 2 THEN UnitPrice * 1.08
    ELSE UnitPrice
    END AS decimal(5,2)) AS 'New Price'                                                                           Use Decimal to round the New Price to 2 decimals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An explicit `CAST` should do.

```
SELECT ProductID, ProductName, WholesalePrice, UnitPrice as [Current Price],
CAST
  (
    CASE
      WHEN CategoryID = 1 or CategoryID = 4 THEN UnitPrice * 1.2
      WHEN CategoryID = 6 or CategoryID = 8 THEN UnitPrice * 1.15
      WHEN SupplierID = 2 THEN UnitPrice * 1.08
      ELSE UnitPrice
    END
  AS decimal(9,2)) AS [New Price]
```

The precision of 9 is a guess. You may need to adjust it for your data. The scale of 2, though, puts two places to the right of the decimal point.

As an aside, I adjusted the non-standard column aliases (containing spaces) to use the SQL Server preferred method of square brackets. You could choose to use double quotes, but single quotes, which denote string literals, have been deprecated for a few versions now and should be avoided.